# How to detect StreamingHttpReponse context in template

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I'm working with `StreamingHttpResponse` my generator response is:

```
def generator():
    for x in range(1, 20):
        yield '<p>x = {}</p>{}\n'.format(x, buffer)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I tried to capture this value and put it into the template code:

```
<div id="gen_x"><here></div>
```

So the real question is how to capture this in frontend or Any django method to sent context when Streaming happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you may be confusing streaming the response with having some variables generated for your template.

`StreamingHttpResponse`'s purpose is passing an iterator back to the WSGI code, so the response can be sent to the client without having to load it all in memory. We're talking about the response as a whole here, so that means no templating, as the template engine works on full documents (that can be twisted a bit). That looks mostly unrelated to your example.

Now about your example, if you want to generate all content from an iterator you have to loop on it. Using `{% for %}` will iterate an iterator until it is exhausted.

---

If you really want to send stuff with a delay like your example suggests (that is, if the `sleep` was not there just for testing purpose), then you're out of luck. The best guess you could have would be:

1. render your template without the generated data (make sure it does not incude the closing `</body></html>` tags).
2. create an iterator that will yield the rendered template, then the generated data.
3. enclose the generated data in a `<script>` tag, whose purpose is to put it at the right place in the page.

That's the right way to make a generator interact as a response. However, that will **only work on a development server**. On any production site, the frontend will buffer the response, and unless it is larger than the buffer, it will be delayed until the generator is exhausted.

**TL;DR** you cannot play "animations" by adding delays in your answer.

Comment: ok got it thanks ... but my goal is to do some `terminal` commands like `repo init` then I want to display those terminal ouput into template ... For this purpose do you really think StreamingHttpReponse is ok or shall do any another ?

Comment: Or otherwise can you explain the third step `enclose the generated data in a <script> tag, whose purpose is to put it at the right place in the page.` How to that ?

Comment: Well, as I wrote, it's not really worth explaining as it will **not** work on a normal setup. Thing is, you cannot do this using a regular http setup. You would need either to use some *server push* technology, or at least have the browser poll the server with some AJAX request to regularly get the progress of the task. That in turns require some task offloading tool such as Celery.